# Segmentation fault (core dumped) error showing after executing "bower start" command in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, bower

I am trying to install bower on my Ubuntu 18.04. That's what I have done by this time:

```
sudo snap install bower --classic
sudo npm install bower -g
```

By this time it should be installed, but when I run bower -v I get the following message:

> Segmentation fault('core' dumped)